# Jenkins failing to start after uninstalling some plugins

Tags: jenkins

We run Jenkins (latest LTS) as a service on Centos 7. Today I uninstalled the following plugins:

```
Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin
GitHub Branch Source Plugin
GitHub API Plugin
GitHub
Mercurial plugin
CVS Plug-in
```

and restarted Jenkins but it failed to start:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins restart
Restarting jenkins (via systemctl):  Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
                                                       [FAILED]
```

The journal gives:

```
$ journalctl -u jenkins
<snip>
systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Jenkins Automation Server...
runuser[23955]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user jenkins by (uid=0)
jenkins[23950]: Starting Jenkins Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Jenkins has failed to create a temporary file in /tmp
jenkins[23950]: at Main.extractFromJar(Main.java:498)
jenkins[23950]: at Main._main(Main.java:243)
jenkins[23950]: at Main.main(Main.java:151)
jenkins[23950]: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
jenkins[23950]: at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
jenkins[23950]: at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2024)
jenkins[23950]: at Main.extractFromJar(Main.java:495)
jenkins[23950]: ... 2 more
runuser[23955]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user jenkins
jenkins[23950]: [FAILED]
systemd[1]: jenkins.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Jenkins Automation Server.
```

/var/lib/jenkins is owned by jenkins.

Any suggestions how to fix please?

Comment: Your error is "`Jenkins has failed to create a temporary file in /tmp`". Usually /tmp is wide open (drwxrxwxrwx).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by a reboot. Was maybe low on /tmp space.